# Load the R output eachtime in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, database, r, apply, rodbc

I have a loop which iterates for each row in a data frame and generates 5 output files
and keep appending on the same file for all the records - the code is working fine.

```
for (n in 1:nrow(Data)) {
    #Initialize the required variables
   (some function ---)   

    #Write the file into the output file

    df1= data.frame (key,value)
    df2= data.frame (key,value)
    df3= data.frame (key,value)
    df4= data.frame (key,value)
    df5= data.frame (key,value)

    write.table(df1, file = paste(pradd,"table1.tsv",sep="/"), append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")
    write.table(df2, file = paste(pradd,"table2.tsv",sep="/"), append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")
    write.table(df3, file = paste(pradd,"table3.tsv",sep="/"), append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")
    write.table(df4, file = paste(pradd,"table4.tsv",sep="/"), append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t")
    write.table(df5, file = paste(pradd,"table5.tsv",sep="/"), append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t") 
}
```

However I wanted to load the output - directly from R to MySQL DB as five tables.
These 5 files are large in size, I have to use a library to load faster into db table.

I am using `RODBC` to connect to MySQL. I can read from MySQL tables into R, by estabilishing a connection. Not sure how to load 5 tables each time - my for loop runs.

Update: 
I have tried the below code - it's loading - but `sqlQuery` is slow .My for loop processing is fast, but when I try to load into the database it is slow.

```
for (i in 1: nrow(Data))
{
(--Some function to create dataset 1 to dataset 4 --- )

# collect the result in dataset1  and  put them in a .txt file and use the .txt file to load into db
write.table(dataset1 , file1.txt, append=False, sep = "\t")
sqlQuery(channel," LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file1.txt' INTO TABLE lta_r_db.file1  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';")

# collect the result in dataset2  and  put them in a .txt file and use the .txt file to load into db
write.table(dataset2 , file2.txt, append=False, sep = "\t")
sqlQuery(channel," LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file2.txt' INTO TABLE lta_r_db.file2  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';")

write.table(dataset3 , file3.txt, append=False, sep = "\t")
sqlQuery(channel," LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file3.txt' INTO TABLE lta_r_db.file3  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';")

write.table(dataset4 , file4.txt, append=False, sep = "\t")
sqlQuery(channel," LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file4.txt' INTO TABLE lta_r_db.file4  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';")

write.table(dataset5 , file5.txt, append=False, sep = "\t")
sqlQuery(channel," LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file5.txt' INTO TABLE lta_r_db.file5  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';")
```

How can I run the above with much improved processing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your data.frame has the same number of variables and the same variable names as the table in your database.

```
#your connection to the MySQL database
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnect()
for (n in 1:nrow(Data)){
    #Initialize the required variables
   (some function ---)   

    #Write the file into the output file

    df1= data.frame (key,value)

    sqlSave(channel = channel, dat = df1, tablename = "table1", append = TRUE)
}
odbcClose(channel)
```

Comment: Its working, however sqlSave is very slow , how can i run faster when inserting more records into it

Comment: How many rows has df1? Just one? sqlSave() can save multiple records at the same time. But that might require you to rewrite some of your code. Have a look at ?sqlQuery() which allows to apply any SQL command on the database.

Comment: i have updated th question based on suggestion. i tried `sqlQuery(channel,"BULK INSERT dbname.tablename FROM 'C:/Users/xx/Desktop/xx/Temp/xx/Fc/df1.txt' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n' )")` However i get Errro:Couldnot SQL:ExecDirect

Comment: I have updated the question,based on your suggestion.But the processing is 10 times better than `sqlSave` , but still it runs for longer time

Comment: I've corrected my code. You don't need to quote df1 in sqlSave.

Comment: write a data.frame to a file and then having sqlQuery to read that file again will cause a lot of overhead. I expect sqlSave to be faster than write.table followed by bulk insert with sqlQuery.

Comment: Is there any other package that can help in improving the loading performance

Answer (score 0):

here you can find another way with fictious data ..
the following code tests repeated insertion of a list of data.frame in a mysql db with `RMySQL::dbWriteTable` using `base::mapply` and `parallel::mcmapply`

Consider also that, in general, the few accesses to the db (and much more data per access), the better is. As an alternative, you may try to pack data in larger tables in R and then export'em to mysql.

However, the mysql side..

```
## mysql> show tables;                                                          
## +----------------+                                                           
## | Tables_in_test |                                                           
## +----------------+                                                           
## | table1         |                                                           
## | table2         |                                                           
## | table3         |                                                           
## | table4         |                                                           
## | table5         |                                                           
## +----------------+                                                           
## 5 rows in set (0.00 sec)                                                     

## mysql> describe table1;                                                      
## +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+                           
## | Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |                           
## +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+                           
## | id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |                           
## | value | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |                           
## +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+                           
## 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

then

```
## ## ----------------------------------------------------------       
## ## A few benchmark                                                  
## ## ----------------------------------------------------------       
## Create some data                                                    
id <- 1:5
val <- rnorm(5)
## you need to have a list of data.frame, eg                           
my.df <- data.frame("id"= 1:5,
                   "value"=rnorm(5))
df.list <- split(my.df, my.df$id)
## otherwise                                                           
## df.list <- list(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5) 
tab.names <- paste("table", 1:5, sep="")                               


## number of repetitions                                               
reps <- 100

clean <- function() {
    dbSendQuery(my.con, "delete from table1")
    dbSendQuery(my.con, "delete from table2")
    dbSendQuery(my.con, "delete from table3")
    dbSendQuery(my.con, "delete from table4")
    dbSendQuery(my.con, "delete from table5")
}

## ## ------------------------------------------------------- 


library(RMySQL)
library(parallel)

my.con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 host = "localhost",
                 dbname = "test",
                 user = "your.username",
                 password = "your.password")

clean()


system.time(
    for (i in 1:reps) {
        mapply(dbWriteTable,
               name=tab.names ,
               value = df.list,
               MoreArgs=list(conn = my.con, append = T,
                   row.names = FALSE))
    })

clean()

system.time(
    for (i in 1:reps) {
        mcmapply(dbWriteTable,
                 name=tab.names ,
                 value = df.list,
                 MoreArgs=list(conn = my.con, append = T,
                     row.names = FALSE),
                 mc.cores = 8,
                 mc.preschedule = FALSE
                 )
    })

clean()


dbDisconnect(my.con)
rm(my.con)
```

I didn't find increased spead using parallelization. 
In the end, at least in my setting, you could use a simple

```
mapply(dbWriteTable,
       name=paste("table", 1:5, sep="") ,
       value = df.list,
       MoreArgs=list(conn = my.con, append = T, row.names = FALSE))
```

I don't use ODBC a lot in unix so i could't test it against RODBC, however HTH.

cheers